# MongoDB Url set with MongoClientOptions

Tags: java, mongodb

I use MongoDB driver 3.4.1 an I will set this URL

```
url = "mongodb://username:password@serverName:27017/databaseName?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&ssl=true";
```

with

```
MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = MongoClientOptions.builder();
```

but I don't know how to set

```
authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&ssl=true";
```

this one with MongoClientOptions?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/authenticating])

With a static factory method:

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(user,
                                                                       database,
                                                                       password);
```

Or in the connection string:

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://user1:pwd1@host1/?authSource=db1&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1");
```